# Left and right justified

Tags: c

Is there any other method to print names in left justified and the numbers in right justified manner in file without using `printf("%10d")` in c language?

Comment: Yes. Convert to string, see how many spaces are missing, and fill them in yourself. Not sure why you'd ever do that.

Comment: can you please explain why you do not want to use this method? that could be useful/required for giving alternative suggestions. also please give concrete test examples, if possible.

Comment: Can you show one input and the expected output scenario, atleast?

Comment: One might want to avoid `printf` because it's a horrible waste of resources on smaller embedded platforms. Newlib would e.g. link in a complicated `malloc` implementation which would not only fill up 32k flash, but also demand a few kBytes of heap space just because I'd like to print a few values in pretty columns to the debug port. Better roll your own when space is tight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
void print_uint32_right_justify(uint32_t num, int width) {           
  char b[width + 2];
  char *p = b + width + 1;
  *(p--) = 0;
  if(!num)
    *(p--) = '0';
  while(num > 0) {
    *(p--) = '0' + num % 10;
    num /= 10;
  }
  while(p > b)
    *(p--) = ' ';
  write(1, b + 1, width);
}
```

Comment: should also check for negative numbers.

Comment: I don't think so, because it's an uint32_t :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `*` width specifier of `printf`.

```
const int length = 20;
char aligned_left[length];
char aligned_right[length];

char *text = "text";

int padding_count = length - strnlen(text, length) - 1;

snprintf(aligned_right, length, "%*s%s", padding_count, "", text);
snprintf(aligned_left, length, "%s%*s", text, padding_count, "");
```

If you want integers, you can either replace `%s` by `%d` (but you have to calculate the length of the integer appropriately) or `snprintf` the int to what I called `char *text` here.

[Run on ideone](http://ideone.com/sr2Mw9)